# Android cant read file after saveWebArchive

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to read the contents of file written using `saveWebArchive()` method, but it says that the file's length is 0 while the file exists and has some data.

Tried to read the file when it exists on the filesystem and disabled the `saveWebArchive()` call. Now it can read it. There must be some synchronizing issue.

```java
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {
                view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('imPage').style.display='none';");
                SystemClock.sleep(3000);
                System.out.println("save: " + myApp.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/myArchive"+".mht");
                view.saveWebArchive(myApp.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/myArchive"+".mht");



                TextView txttitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titletxt);
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();

 StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        File file = null;
            final Context myApp = this;
            File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            file = new File(myApp.getExternalFilesDir(null),"myArchive.mht");
            System.out.println("Size:" + file.length());
            }
```

The file myArchive.mht is expected to be opened and read after calling to `saveWebArchive()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked! Just use `saveWebArchive()` with callback option. Like that:

```
view.saveWebArchive(myApp.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/myArchive"+".mht", false, callback);
```